# Чи має вираз "копати криниченьку" ідіоматичне значення дотичне статевих відносин?

Tags: етимологія, значення-слів, фразеологізми

На одній з ігор виду "Що? Де? Коли?", яка мала тему "Чорний гумор, непристойності", було поставлено питання про прихований зміст вислову "копав криниченьку". Цей вислів, нібито, має відношення до статевого акту.

Самого питання, на жаль, вже не пригадаю, але якщо не помиляюсь, воно стосувалось вживання виразу "копав криниченьку" в українській народній пісні [«Розпрягайте, хлопці, коні»](http://nashe.com.ua/song/5752).

**Чи дійсно вираз "копати криниченьку" має ідіоматичне значення, дотичне статевих відносин?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Детальним дослідженням цієї теми є книга [Українські сороміцькі пісні](http://proridne.com/content/%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96/), Видавництво «Фоліо», Харків — 2003. Упорядкування, передмова, примітки канд. філол. наук М. М. Красикова. Криниця там згадується в єдиній пісні, [Під столом криниця](http://proridne.com/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96/%D0%9F%D0%86%D0%94%20%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9C%20%D0%9A%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A6%D0%AF.html), пісня ж «Розпрягайте, хлопці, коні» там не згадується взагалі.

Answer (score 16):

У словнику нецензурної лексики "Українська мова без табу" Лесі Ставицької:

> КРИНИ́ЦЯ, ж., фольк.-поет. Піхва

Answer (score 12):

Ще й як має! Це все дуже смішно, особливо про "чари", але з фольклором жарти короткі:

> Загалом вода символізує дівчину, жінку, їхню красу й "жіночі чари", що
>   наповнюють осіб прекрасної статі. Свою воду — дівочу вроду — дівчата
>   пильно охороняли. Бо коли хлопець передчасно нап'ється води чи розі­
>   б'ється посудина, в якій зберігається ота чарівна рідина, буде дівчині
>   лихо. Дівчину, її вроду символізує в народних піснях і посуд (який наповнює
>   вода): відро, барило, а також криниця. Чим глибша кри­ ниця, чим легше
>   в ній потонути, тим краща врода дівчини. Коли посудина з водою
>   протікає, це означає невірність дівчини, жінки. Напоїти коня в
>   народних піснях — все одно, що дати напитися хлопцеві: тобто
>   подарувати своє кохання.

Аж настільки короткі:

> У пісні про кохання дівчина відмовляється посто­яти з хлопцем біля
>   криниці й напоїти коня, бо "зимна роса, а дівчина боса —
>   ніженьки щемлять". Козак їй на те від­повідає: "Ой скину я опанчу, та
>   ніженьки обверчу. Ой дай, Боже, неділі діждати — черевички куплю"...

**Джерело**: "100 найвідоміших образів української міфології" (2002)

Тобто вона ніби й не проти, а ніби й страшно, бо в українській культурі "збезчещених" дівчат йой як не любили. Зрештою, козак виявляється достатньо винахідливим, щоби спокусити невиннеє дівча черевичками (символ шлюбу). Це, до речі, пояснює, чому в народних піснях він ніколи не може сам набрати з криниці води й напоїти коня, давши дівчині чистий спокій. Якщо дівчина сильна й незалежна, буде багато люті й праведного гніву, якщо ж вона таки вийде до криниці - всім спокійно, всі задоволені (окрім дівчини, звісно, бо це їй потім ворота дьогтем вимажуть, хату розтрощать і батьків поб'ють) - от, власне, й казочці кінець.

Answer (score 10):

Можливо, вас зацікавить інтерв'ю: https://youtu.be/pRkzPTqZ-Dk?t=578

Пані етнологиня вважає, що багато народних соромницьких пісень мають сексуальний підтекст, тому можна припустити, що "копати криниченьку" теж має ідіоматичне значення дотичне до статевих відносин, але я не впевнений в цьому.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com. Будь ласка, додайте арґументацію пані етнолоґині до вашої відповіді, щоби інформація містилися у відповіді, і задля її здобуття не треба було переходити за посиланням.